# PowerApps search by a column having multiple values

Tags: search, sharepoint, lookup, powerapps, multivalue

I have a PowerApps application for which the backend source is SharePoint. I have a requirement where I need to search by the table tables. So, I used the formula -

```
Sort(
  Filter(Table_name, inputSearch_3.Text in ColumnA || inputSearch_3.Text in ColumnB),
  ColumnA,SortOrder.Ascending
)
```

Now I got a new requirement where I need to search by another column too but that column columnC has multiple values which is the lookup for another table (Table_name1, column ColumnD) having single values.

Can you please modify the above query and provide me a query which can search by columnC also.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sort(
  Filter(
    Table_name,
    inputSearch_3.Text in ColumnA ||
    inputSearch_3.Text in ColumnB ||
    CountRows( Filter(ColumnC, StartsWith(Value, inputSearch_3.Text) ) ) > 0
  ),
  ColumnA, SortOrder.Ascending
)
```